# How to use Promises correctly with multiple requests

Tags: node.js, api, twitter, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am using twitter's API to receive recent tweets by querying specific hash tags. The first GET request is to `search/tweets` which takes the hashtag and others queries in it's parameters. The response for this returns an array of tweets (objects). I push each of these id's into an external array. Now I want to loop through this array and make another call to `statuses/show` for each of these IDs so that I can get the location data of the user posting the tweet. The `statuses/show` end-point only takes a single tweet id but I have an array. How would I go about using the same `getRequest` function for an array of IDs?

I tried to implement it by reading online about Promises but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
function getRequest(url, params) {
    return new Promise(function (success, failure) {
        twitterSearch.get(url, params, function (error, body, response) {
            if (!error) {
                success(body);
            } else {
                failure(error);
            }
        });
    });
}

app.post('/twitter', (req, res) => {
  console.log("body", req.body);
  var tweetIDs = [];
  var bounds = [];
  getRequest('search/tweets', {q: req.body.tag, result_type:'recent', count:'100'})
  .then((tweets) => {
    tweets.statuses.map((status) => {
      if(status.user.geo_enabled) {
        console.log("ID: ", status.id);
        tweetIDs.push(status.id);
      }
    });
    return getRequest('statuses/show', tweetIDs); //I know tweetIDs is wrong, dont know what to do from here.
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log("User data for the ID")
    console.log(data);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error)
  });
  res.send(bounds);
  bounds.length = 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nearly got it right! Map all tweets to Promises returned by your `getRequest()` function. Then, the [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method will return you a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in your array resolves.
By the way, you can use `Array.reduce` instead of `map` to both filter and map your array at the same time, this factor your code a little better.

```
getRequest('search/tweets', {q: req.body.tag, result_type:'recent', count:'100'})

  .then( tweets => {
    let requests = tweets.statuses.reduce( (ret,status) => {
      if(status.user.geo_enabled)
          // The following is still wrong though, I guess. Format the params of getRequest accordingly.
          ret.push( getRequest('statuses/show', status.id) );
      return ret;
    }, []);
    return Promise.all(requests);
  })

  .then( results => {
     results.forEach( res => {
        console.log("User data for the ID");
        console.log(res);
     })
  })
```

**EDIT :** Related [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6jmovpn/10/)

Comment: I was getting an error that `ret.push` is not a function. After reading more about reduce I made the following changes -> https://gyazo.com/885226def49e85742636373551d104e8 but i'm still getting these errors -> https://gyazo.com/c4754ebb822ad4e20e47c2fdba3d513c

Comment: `reduce` is the (rough) equivalent of: `let ret = []; arr.forEach( item => if(//something) ret.push(item) )`. You can try it like this for now I guess.

Comment: anything that is returned within the reduce functions callback, is pushed to the accumulator variable. In my previous comment, the first link contains the code i wrote. Can you tell me if `line 57` will return an array of promises into `ret` and thus into `requests` or just `ret`?

Comment: I think i am getting that error on `line 60` because `requests` is undefined

Comment: @ShashankKaul I created a jsfiddle for you, hoping you can solve your issue ;) Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k6jmovpn/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line

```
return getRequest('statuses/show', tweetIDs); //I know tweetIDs is wrong, dont know what to do from here.
```

with

```
return Promisel.all( tweetIDs.map( (tId) => getRequest('statuses/show', tId) );
```

Comment: Code: https://gyazo.com/a969f9d793f1f92f92a68965a4328315 

Console: https://gyazo.com/32747ee0b44260fb6dc486812219f516
It isnt making the second request correctly.

Comment: In the api of twitter that error code means, the tweet was deleted.

Comment: Check 144 under title Error Codes here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/response-codes.html